# Fullcalendar event population issue: javascript does not fire

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3, fullcalendar

I am having a good deal of trouble populating the jQuery FullCalendar with events.

Browser: IE8

Tech: MVC 3 Razor

Scripts in use: jquery-1.5.1, fullcalendar.js

Controller and supporting method: (even though my issue is that it never gets here in the first place)

```
     public JsonResult GetCalendarData()
    {
        List<CourseSection> courseSecs = //genarates list of course sections from db context
        var listOfEvents = new List<object>();

        foreach (CourseSection courseSec in courseSecs)
        {
            Course course = db.Course.Find(courseSec.CourseID);
            listOfEvents.Add(
            new
            {
                id = courseSec.ID,
                title = course.Name + "Section " + courseSec.Name,
                start = ToUnixTimespan(courseSec.sectionBeginDateAndDailyStartTime),
                end = ToUnixTimespan(courseSec.sectionEndDateAndDailyEndTime),
                allDay = false //none of the course sections run all day
            });
        }

        return Json(listOfEvents.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
    private string ToUnixTimespan(DateTime date) //supporting method
    {
        TimeSpan tspan = date.ToUniversalTime().Subtract(
        new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0));

        return Math.Truncate(tspan.TotalSeconds).ToString();
    }
```

View:

```
    @model Web.Models.Registration

     @{
     ViewBag.Title = "ViewSchedule";
     Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_SiteLayout.cshtml";
     }

     <script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
     // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
     $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
              defaultView: "agendaWeek",
              year: 2013,
              month: 0,
              date: 25,
              minTime: 6,
              maxTime: 18,
              aspectRatio: 1.5,
              allDaySlot: false,
              events: "/Course/GetCalandarData"
              });
     });
     </script>


     <div class="wrapper col3">
       <div id="container">
         <h1>View Schedule</h1>
           <div id = 'calendar'>
           </div>
        <br />
        @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Home", "Static")
        <br />
       </div>
     </div>
```

Issue: The calendar itself and all of the configurations load fine. However, the last line of configuration (events: "/Course/GetCalendarData") does NOT fire. Period. It never trips any of the debug blocks I have placed in the controller method, and no JSON is returned.

I have tried adding in the obligatory "@Url.Content..." prefix to the access URL. I have tried housing the method in a different controller. I have tried using a different version of jQuery. I have removed all extraneous scripts that may have been causing a conflict. All for nada.

I've been tearing my hair out over this. Any ideas?

Comment: start by inspecting the actual AJAX request in a browser console and see what it's doing. Can see status, data sent/received etc as well see url it is using

Comment: I inspected the AJAX request/site activity in the profiler tool via Dev Tools. I can see when the view is called clear enough, but after that it's just a flurry of activity between jQuery and the  fullcalendar script. There is an "_addEventSource" function, but its inclusive and exclusive time are both 0. And no calls are made to Course/GetCalendarData. Which is where it should be going....

Comment: is data returned? Is it valid json in format that calendar wants? Can see response when inspecting request

Comment: As near as I can tell, no data is being returned. It is in a valid format, as I have tested this exact same thing as part of a standalone solution and it works fine there...Could you give me something specific to check/instructions to check something you have in mind? I'm not sure what I'm looking for...

Comment: in browser console f12 in chrome, or Firebug in Firefox can see the full request in `Net` or `Network` tab. WIll show status- needs to be 200, and can see exactly what server sends back. If no data sent back and url is correct and status is 200, something wrong in sever code. Also a 500 will tell you that server code is failing

Comment: Unfortunately, I am stuck in IE8...much to my dismay, I don't have access to any of those highly useful tools :-( Any other ideas or ways I could get more detailed info using just the IE8 developer tools?

Comment: install IE developer tools to use console, Chrome has built in console, Firebug is awesome in Firefox. All are free and easy and fats to install

Answer (score 1):

So after many hours of debugging, I discovered a workaround.

Instead of initiating a JSON request from the view to the GetCalendarData method, I modified the controller code and moved it to a separate static class. I then use that to return a plain array of objects, and then convert the array to JSON on the fly in the view. Observe:

Controller and support method:

```
    public static object[] GetCalendarData()
    {
    List<CourseSection> courseSecs = //list of course sections from db context
    var listOfEvents = new List<object>();

        foreach (CourseSection courseSec in courseSecs)
        {
            Course course = db.Course.Find(courseSec.CourseID);
            listOfEvents.Add(
                new
                {
                    id = courseSec.ID,
                    title = course.Name + "Section " + courseSec.Name,
                    start = ToUnixTimespan(courseSec.sectionBeginDateAndDailyStartTime),
                    end = ToUnixTimespan(courseSec.sectionEndDateAndDailyEndTime),
                    allDay = false
                });
        }

        return listOfEvents.ToArray();

    }

    public static string ToUnixTimespan(DateTime date)
    {
        TimeSpan tspan = date.ToUniversalTime().Subtract(
     new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0));

        return Math.Truncate(tspan.TotalSeconds).ToString();
    }
```

View:
        @model Web.Models.Registration

```
    @{  
        ViewBag.Title = "ViewSchedule";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_SiteLayout.cshtml";
    }

    @{
        object[] events = Web.Extensions.CourseOps.GetCalendarData();
    }

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var allSections = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(events));
            // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultView: "agendaWeek",
        year: 2013,
        month: 0,
        date: 25,
        minTime: 6,
        maxTime: 18,
        aspectRatio: 1.5,
        allDaySlot: false,
        events: allSections,
        // put your options and callbacks here
    });

        });
    </script>


    <div class="wrapper col3">
      <div id="container">
        <h1>View Schedule</h1>
        <div id = 'calendar'>
        </div>
         <br />
        @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Home", "Static")
        <br />
      </div>
    </div>
```

The fact that my original javascript configuration (events: "/Course/GetCalendarData") did not fire could possibly be attributed to the Authorization Attributes I have on my controllers, or the rather aggressive way I check for authenticated cookies, but that's kind of getting into the weeds.

The point is, I found a successful workaround and I am satisfied.

Special thanks to "charlietfl" for sticking with me and doing his best to help.

Till next time...